# Trouble starting jupyter notebook

Tags: python, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook

Apparently I do have it installed, but it won't start

```
 jupyter --version
4.4.0
ThinkPad-T520:~$ ipython jupyter
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | File not found: u'jupyter'
```

Other relevant parameters:

```
python --version
Python 2.7.14
ThinkPad-T520:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jupyter notebook`

^^ thats the command to run

Answer (score 1):

ipython and Jupyter are 2 different programs. You need to just run the `jupyter` command.